# Color space belongs to which one?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, colors

I'm having a color camera which is having its specific color space. Shall we consider that, when I'm acquiring image from it, saving them in imageData, accessing their pixels, using openCV, and declaring them (as below): that the RGB color space will be sRGB since OpenCV belongs to that color space?

```
 IplImage *A1=cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
 IplImage *A2=cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
 IplImage *A3=cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default color format in OpenCV is often referred to as RGB but it is actually BGR. So, when you load an image, by default it is read in BGR format, even if it is not.

If you know color space of your camera, use cvtColor as below. If you don't, try to play with cvtColor function and find the best looking image; since there is no algorithm that can detect default camera color space.

```
// suppose camera outputs RGB
Mat img = imread("..."); // loaded as BGR
cvtColor(img, img, CV_RGB2BGR); // corrected now.
```

Please read through this [explanation](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/vision/opencv/iplimage.html).

Comment: Yes sir. OpenCV completely ignores camera output when displaying or processing an image. Instead it chooses to assume BGR order, and this can lead to strange image output if displayed using cvShowImage.